# Wicket and JSPs

Tags: jsp, wicket

Using `add(new Include())` syntax, I was able to include jsps which are at the top level.

However those which are present inside 'WEB-INF' cannot be referenced, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Include class makes an external request instead of including/forwarding current one, which makes your case impossible. WEB-INF is not available to external requests, only include/forward if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to include both inside one application? If I were you, and if you are in fact trying to migrate from JSP to Wicket, I would create a new Wicket application which you could mount under a separate context path on your server, and let Wicket sit by itself. You can then also include resources such as css and js from the other application directly, avoiding any repetition.